# asp.net MVC Model Binding a byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the need to accept a byte array from a model and have it bound correctly. This is not for a file, but to protect sensitive information in a string from being interned and thus in memory forever. I have the following model class. This is in a much larger model and I don't want to have a separate action in it for this piece.

```
public class ParentModel 
{
    //a lot of properties
    public SensitiveData Sensitive { get; set; }
}

public class SensitiveData
{
    public byte[] Value { get; set; }
}
```

The return response will be

```
public class ParentViewModel 
{
    //a lot of properties
    public SensitiveDataViewModel Sensitive {get;set;}
}

public class SensitiveDataViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Maksed { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}
```

I understand that this could be a multipart upload, but the byte array will be at most 32 characters, and it isn't a file. If it was a string, it would be stuck in clear text in memory. I can't make the application bullet proof, but I do want the data to be cleared out as soon as it can be so that I am making it harder to get at this data and reduce the amount of time it lives in memory. I can't do anything about what MVC does to this if it puts the whole request in a string.

Comment: Have you considered encrypting this information, instead of separating it to bytes? and only decryp when you need to use the information.

Comment: What's your question? With posting only a part of your Model, you can't expect people to be able to help you.

Comment: What about SecureString?

Comment: I will be encrypting the information, but first someone has to send it to me. I want to be able to use SecureString, but if it gets passed into the model as a string, it still gets interned before it goes to SecureString.

After I get the value, I'll be passing back an ID, masked, and a hash.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does your `byte` array not bind correctly?

Answer (score 0):

One way around this could be to use the CompilationRelaxationsAttribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxationsattribute.aspx

From the msdn docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.intern.aspx):

> The .NET Framework version 2.0 introduces the
>   CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning enumeration member. The
>   NoStringInterning member marks an assembly as not requiring
>   string-literal interning. You can apply NoStringInterning to an
>   assembly using the CompilationRelaxationsAttribute attribute.